# SwingX and JToggleButton

Tags: swing, swingx, jtogglebutton

In my application i'm using JXButton from the SwingX library, i really like the painter methods.  Now i have to change my simple button to toggle button and have different painter for the unselected/selected state.  Unfortunately i couldn't find JXToggleButton.  Is there a solution to keep the benefit of painter methods ?

Answer (score 0):

It's actually fairly easy to create a JXType component. You may need to do some extra checks for borders, focus, etc.. but this is the general approach you would take

```
public class JXToggleButton extends JToggleButton implements FocusListener, Paintable {
    private Painter<JTextField> backgroundPainter;
    private Painter<JTextField> foregroundPainter;

    public void setBackgroundPainter(Painter<JTextField> painter) {
        this.backgroundPainter = painter;
    }

    public void setForegroundPainter(Painter<JTextField> painter) {
        this.foregroundPainter = painter;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        if (backgroundPainter != null) {
            this.backgroundPainter.paint((Graphics2D) g, this, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

        super.paintComponent(g);

        if (foregroundPainter != null) {
            foregroundtPainter.paint((Graphics2D) g, this, getWidth(), getHeight());
        }

    }
}
```